# Magento 2.1.4. Change font

Tags: magento2, fonts

I am trying to import a font (have Luma theme installed) with no success. Browsed similar threads about this, made changes in typography and variable files, but still can't get rid of the default 'Open sans' font.

Here's my css file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Chalet';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: url('C:xampp/htdocs/testshop/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-  luma/web/fonts/LEGO-Chalet-60-Tab-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: local('Chalet'), local('Chalet'),
url('../fonts/LEGO-Chalet-60-Tab-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */

   url('../fonts/LEGO-Chalet-60-Tab-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
   url('C:xampp/htdocs/testshop/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-  luma/web/fonts/LEGO-Chalet-60-Tab-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */

}  (tried also full local path)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento Docs
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html

Looks like the path is not correct 
should be

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/fonts

Comment: Already tried that. Actually this path in my installation is app/design/frontend/Magento and then empty.

Comment: So then You installed via composer. path is vendor/magento/theme-frontend-  luma/web/fonts/LEGO-Chalet-60-Tab-Regular.ttf  so use     @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/LEGO-Chalet-60-Tab-Regular.ttf',

Comment: '@{baseDir}fonts/LEGO-Chalet-60-Tab-Regular.ttf - In which file will this go? css or other file? Because I tried both the css and typography.less and still doesn't work, I'm frustrated... :/

Comment: so this worked out ?